# Sharepoint List Permissions And Admin Override

Tags: 2013, list, permissions

EDIT: This is being hosted through Office 365

I need to put together a folder where all users will submit their timesheets, but they can only see and edit their own. I want 3 admins who can see and edit everything in that folder.

I've spent about 20 working hours on this, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've created custom groups, I've messed with list settings, user permissions, group permissions, I've looked at countless tutorials. Is this even possible to achieve without separate folders?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

if it is a sharepoint list then it is really easy.

- First open the SharePoint list.
- Select List Settings from the Ribbon.
- Then Select Advanced Settings. The Advanced Settings page will open.
- In the Advanced settings page In the Item-level Permissions section,
  under Read access, Select "Read items that were created by the user"
- And In the Item-level Permissions section, under Create and Edit
  access, select "Create items and edit items that were created by the
  user."

[Changing the Item-Level Permissions Settings for a Document Library requires PowerShell](http://www.hersheytech.com/Blog/SharePoint/tabid/197/entryid/28/Default.aspx)

Comment: I would vote you up, but I require more reputation :/

Comment: I'd like to add that I cannot do these Power Shell commands, as this is via Office 365. Is it true that without Power Shell add-ins and a dedicated Sharepoint server, that doing this won't be possible?

Comment: I did not get it? do you want to set that permission using powershell or what?  By the way, it is your question, you can mark this as anwser if it solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We implemented a similar solution using Nintex workflows. Our approach was to break the permission on the item when it is created and set permission for author and admin user group alone.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Waqas' solution, I would edit the document library page, and add a second instance of the library webpart. In the first library webpart (that should have already been on the page), I'd edit the view to filter the Modified By field to [Me]. I would leave the second webpart (the one you added), but use Audience Targeting to only make it visible to the owner or admin security group.

Using this method, the users will only see the timesheets they have entered or modified using the first webpart, and only the admins will see the second webpart that give them access to everything. You also don't have to worry about the users changing views and seeing content because there is only the one default view.